# Why is binding hammer.js to document body not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, touch-event, hammer.js

I want to use hammer.js to capture mobile touch inputs. As some elements (e.g., some 'li') are dynamically generated, I want to bind the hammer object to document itself, and use a selector to capture the events.

```
var hammer=Hammer(document.body);
hammer.on("release",'.touchzone',function(ev){
  alert(ev.gesture);
});
```

The code above doesn't work - there is no alert and the function is not entered. However, I directly attached the `hammer` object to the element `div.touchzone` could work.

```
var hammer=Hammer($('.touchzone')[0]);
hammer.on("release", function(ev){alert(ev.gesture);});
```

I use jQuery 1.11.0, and the v1.0.9 hammer.min.js (with size of ~13kb).

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because `$('.touchzone')[0]` return a native DOM object, not a jQuery object.

To apply jQuery along with Hammer, you can make use of **[jQuery Hammer](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js)** plugin.

Include it after jQuery, then you can do:

```
$(document.body).hammer().on('release', '.touchzone', function(ev){
    alert(ev.gesture);
});
```

Comment: Yes. I didn't import jquery.hammer so it couldn't use the selector in that way. With the plugin, it can work now in browsers. Well, I am using it in phonegap mobile apps, and in the app it says the object has no method 'hammer'...Anyway, I'll try to capture the events with inherent touchstart, touchend, etc listeners myself...